# Phoenix 1.4 server is delivering default HTML instead of requested JS files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, phoenix-framework, vue-router

I am trying to render Vue.js directly in my Phoenix 1.4 application. But the following error is occurring after installing Vue-router:

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4000/0.app.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

My Phoenix router.ex file looks as follows:

```
scope "/", Web do
 pipe_through :browser
 get "/*path", PageController, :index
end
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  entry: {
    './js/app.js': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js'])
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              fiber: require('fibers'),
              indentedSyntax: true // optional
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }]),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
});
```

I am currently seeing an issue with (I think) the cache manifest whereby my site delivers HTML and CSS files properly but for JS files, the default HTML template is being delivered - which results in an erro.

I can see in the Chrome Dev Tools Network tab that the response from this request http://localhost:4000/0.app.js is the app.html.eex file.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Phoenix Framework</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vue-app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a wildcard catch-all route to show your index page, and requests to resources are hitting that route, this means that `Plug.Static` is not set up correctly in your `endpoint.ex`.

Ours looks something like this:

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :my_app_name, gzip: true,
  only: ~w(css images js favicon.ico robots.txt fonts)
```

put that anywhere before you do `plug MyApp.Router`.

Another reason could be that `0.app.js` simply doesn't exist in `priv/static/js`. Check there to see if it isn't actually called `app.js` or has a hash appended to its name.